# Z39.50 Zoom.Net.YazSharp Set sort, start and offset record to Retrieve part of results only

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, dll, marc, z39.50

I am using Zoom.Net.YazSharp to communicate with other libraries using Z39.50 protocol. The issue when I send a query and the results returns with many records, my application hanging if you try to loop on those records. So I need a way to limit the number of returned records by Sorting and set Start and Offset record. I founded this feature exists in PHP and C version of YAZ library but I cannot find it for C# version.

Please I need to help.